# How to filter by column

Tags: awk, grep, ps

Surprisingly hard to find a good example of this one. Say I have this command:

```
ps -aeF
```

the 7th column is the processor # (?). I just want to filter by processses running on the 2nd core. How can I do that? The problem of course if if I do:

```
ps -aeF | awk '{print $7}' | grep 2
```

then I only get single column not printing all the columns..

Comment: You mean like `... | awk '$7==2'` ?

Comment: yeah like that please add an answer, that is nicer than the `if` block that I had in my awk command so it's an improvement on what I found with my search

Comment: Great question! Came here looking for same. It's surprising to me that Unix doesn't have a standard `filter` command for with a syntax analogous to `sort`. (Presumably because `awk` can do it so easily, but the '$x==y' syntax is not covered in most `awk` examples you can find on the web.)

Answer (score 5):

Awk scripts consist of pairs of *patterns* and *actions* that are executed when the pattern evaluates logically true. So you can use

```
... | awk '$7==2 {print}'
```

or more succinctly, because `{print}` is the default action

```
... | awk '$7==2'
```

Comment: Note that if the pattern you're matching is a string, not a number, you need to quote it: `awk '$7=="foo"'`.